# Wrapping a div around "document.createElement"

Tags: javascript, css

it seems like a small problem, but i dont get a solution.

```
tableAdd: function(entry) {
    var $tr = document.createElement('div'), $td, key;
    $tr.setAttribute("class", "mylist_zeile clearfix");

    for (key in entry) {
        if (entry.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

            $td = document.createElement("div");
            $td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry[key]));
            $tr.appendChild($td);
            $td.setAttribute("class", "mylist_spalte");

        }
    }
    $td = document.createElement("span");
    $td.setAttribute("class", "mylist_remove");
    $td.innerHTML = '<a data-op="remove" data-id="'+ entry.id +'">X</a>';
    $tr.appendChild($td);
    $tr.setAttribute("id", "entry-"+ entry.id);

    mylist.$table.appendChild($tr);
}
```

...gives me:

```
<div id="entry-1" class="mylist_zeile clearfix">
    <div class="mylist_spalte">1</div>
    <div class="mylist_spalte">Title One</div>
    <div class="mylist_spalte">http://www.google.com/someurl1</div>
    <span class="mylist_remove">
        <a data-id="1" data-op="remove">X</a>
    </span>
</div>
<div id="entry-2" class="mylist_zeile clearfix">
    <div class="mylist_spalte">2</div>
    <div class="mylist_spalte">Title Two</div>
    <div class="mylist_spalte">http://www.google.com/someurl2</div>
    <span class="mylist_remove">
        <a data-id="2" data-op="remove">X</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

thats fine until now. now i need to wrap those 3 divs with the class `"mylist_spalte"` with another div (with the class `"mylist_wrapper"`. and every div with the class `"mylist_spalte"` should get an other class:

first div: `"row_1"`

second div: `"row_2"`

third div: `"row_3"`

any ideas?

Comment: You'd probably get more answers if you distilled your question down  to a simpler example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use classList object instead setAttribute.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList

Then wrap everything inside another div, this should e pretty easy, try this code

```
tableAdd: function(entry) {
    var $tr = document.createElement('div'),
        $wrap = document.createElement('div'),
        $td, key;
    $tr.setAttribute("class", "mylist_zeile clearfix");
    $wrap.setAttribute("class", "mylist_wrapper");
    var count = 0;
    for (key in entry) {
        if (entry.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            count++;
            $td = document.createElement("div");
            $td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry[key]));
            $td.classList.add("mylist_spalte");
            $td.classList.add("row_"+count);
            $wrap.appendChild($td);

        }
    }
    $tr.appendChild($wrap);
    $td = document.createElement("span");
    $td.setAttribute("class", "mylist_remove");
    $td.innerHTML = '<a data-op="remove" data-id="'+ entry.id +'">X</a>';
    $tr.appendChild($td);
    $tr.setAttribute("id", "entry-"+ entry.id);

    mylist.$table.appendChild($tr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
var $parentdiv = document.createElement('div');
 var $tr = document.createElement('div'), $td, key;
// in the end of $tr assignment/operations 
$parentdiv.appendChild($tr);
 mylist.$table.appendChild($tr);
```